# Careers is unable to include my site’s favicon

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

My Stack Overflow Careers profile includes links to a couple of my projects, and their websites contain markup like

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="16x16 32x32" type="image/png"
 href="/myproject/favicon.png"/>
```

Instead of displaying the favicons, though, SO Careers displays a placeholder (a white box with a gray border). I think everything here is valid HTML5, except for the inclusion of `shortcut` in the `rel` attribute (which is necessary for IE)… am I doing something wrong, or is SOC parsing my site incorrectly?

Comment: Any reason you can't include them in an `img` element?

Comment: @Oded: It’s a favicon, why would I include it in an `img`?

Comment: Why do you expect a favicon to appear on a _page_?

Comment: Not sure it's a "bug", maybe they just not covering all  the corners. Good test case will be checking your favicon [here](http://g.etfv.co/http://www.stackoverflow.com) just change `http://www.stackoverflow.com` to your own URL and see what you get. If it's the correct icon than you can ask the developers here to fill the gap for your case.

Comment: Also note that based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119041/how-can-i-get-a-web-sites-favicon) posted by Stack Overflow developer, full URL is expected in the `href` attribute so most likely changing to full URL will make it work for your case as well.

Comment: @Oded When you link to a project via your Stack Overflow Careers profile, SOC tries to import the website’s favicon to show next to the link.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd This tool correctly finds the favicon for the root of my domain (/index.html), but fails on the page in question, which has its own favicon. (This is an issue with the getFavicon tool, as noted under “known problems” at [the bottom of the page](http://g.etfv.co/).) And I’m not sure where on that SO answer anyone says that you need a full URL… I think that the HTML spec itself specifies how to resolve URLs that are given relative to the root of the current domain, and my page is in compliance with the spec.

Comment: Sorry, linked to the question instead to answer. [Here is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5119105/447356) link to the answer itself, as you see Marc is giving full URL in there. As code need to be changed it might take time, can't you change the URL in your page in the meanwhile?

Comment: Can you give an example link for testing?

Comment: @mjibson Both http://www.bdesham.info and http://www.bdesham.info/cubuses exhibit this behavior.

Comment: I tried both URLs as article read/written, open source, and apps & software and the correct favicon was displayed. Try again?